# The word cavernous

Tags: word-usage

I wonder   in what contexts "**cavernous**" can be used as a synonym for "**spacious**" or "**big/huge**".

The word **cavernous** is derived from the word **cave** but does it necessary the things we refer as cavernous must  have a large cavity like a hall in a building, hotel,shopping center or airport or can we use it for buildings that expands  large area such as  a 50-room mansion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Cavernous* means *like a cavern*, and a *cavern* means a big, open *space* within a cave, which is underground.

It's not appropriate for entire buildings, which are typically above ground.  Rooms can be described as cavernous, though, especially something like a large room tucked away beneath stairs or other structure in a building.

You might describe the ground floor halls in that mansion as *cavernous* if they are big and open.